# CSV column data is being truncated

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I am parsing a CSV file using Jet with the connection string

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + directory + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited';"
```

with a Schema.ini containing:

```
[SelfCatering.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=0
```

In my c# code I have predefined the column data types as string but for some reason extended string columns are being truncated at 255 characters. If I quick watch the column data itself is it only 255 letters long

Where else would it be getting truncated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `Jet OLEDB 4.0` driver, it will truncate your long text to 255 chars and it will read only 255 columns/fields. If you have more than 255 columns/fields you will not be able to read them all.

Other people on StackOverflow suggests to use: [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should try `Datatype LongChar` I had success with it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify MaxScanRows=0.
It is not working for some reason.
Tried MaxScanRows=1000.  It is working.
or alternatively try edit registry

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Text]
"MaxScanRows"=dword:00001000

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the field types in your Schema.ini file:

```
<SelfCatering.csv>
   You can add comments here
</SelfCatering.csv>

<schema.ini>
[SelfCatering.csv]
ColNameHeader=TRUE
MaxScanRows=0
Format=CSVDelimited
Col1=ColName1 Text Width 50
Col2=ColName2 Text Width 50
Col3=ColName3 Text Width 500
</schema.ini>
```

Comment: Actually, the more I think of it, I think that 255 is the max field size or the Jet engine. You may try defining he fields as memo instead of text. But why aren't you using framework o read a CSV file.